# AbstractMethodError when try to initialize Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, slf4j

I'm developing an application with Spring, vaadin and maven like tool di project managment. 
Now when try to execute jetty:run i get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
```

This is my pom.xml

```
  <!-- Logging dependencies   -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Log4J dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There's a compatibility issue between your logging libraries.

Comment: Why do you have `com.springsource` slf4j artifacts included, and why so many different versions? This error generally means, by the way, that the API class is defining an abstract method, but you're pulling in an old version of the implementing class that doesn't implement that method.

Comment: Any suggestion on what i have to change to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I solved commenting this two dependencies:

```
     <!-- Log4J dependencies 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.slf4j.api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.log4j.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
```

Answer (score 2):

There is conflict with the logging dependency that you have managed. Replace your dependency with below: This will resolve your dependency issue

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.26</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Getting the same error even when using this dependency hierarchy.

Comment: @ChandraMohan ... This is related to your dependency versions. Can you post your pom ?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to upgrade logback from 4.7 to 5.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```